# Free Memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, free-command

When I run free command on my computer, I see the following output:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1877       1802         74          0        125       1541
-/+ buffers/cache:        135       1742
Swap:         2047          0       2047
```

No matter how much I use memory, the `free` column in the 1st row always stays around 70 MB and doesn't drop below (I tried this by loading large files into memory, evident by `cached` being so high)

My understanding is that Linux reserves some memory for the root user always. Is this the reason why the free never drops below 70 MB?

EDIT: If this is the case, then loading the same files as root user should take up all free memory. Unfortunately, I've been unable to do this as well.

Comment: Are you getting malloc failures or other out of memory errors?

Comment: My motivation is to understand why the free memory never drops to 0. In reality, I'm able to produce `OutOfMemory` error in Java but the free memory doesn't drop to zero even with the error.

I just want to understand is some of the available memory reserved for some purpose?

Comment: The Java JVM has it's own heap, with a default that can be overridden by the -Xmx option.  You can run out of memory in a JVM without running out of RAM in the OS.  If you really want your OS to run out of memory, it's better to use a small C program like the one described at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html

Comment: I set the Xmx to 6GB when I ran it and started adding random Strings to a List. The Swap was ultimately all used before I got `OutofMemory` but the free memory never dropped below 65.

Answer (score 3):

You still have lots of RAM available.   You can tell that because:

1. The free column shows 1742 meg free in cache.
2. You are using 0% swap (assuming you haven't run swapoff to disable swapping)

See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for a good explanation of those columns.

Comment: Yes but why doesn't free memory ever go to zero?

Comment: @user3063877: Because `vm.min_free_kbytes` is not zero. Try running `sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes` to see what it is set to. And if you want your cached memory back right away (no reason to except maybe benchmarking), try `system -w vm.drop_caches=3`. The latter requires root.

Comment: Ah, this is it: `sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes`. Thank you. Wish you had answered the question so I could've accepted (Still would if you do :) )